# How to require scripts in Mongo Shell CLI

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to be able to import a library of common tools that I use to make working with MongoDB easier.  However, I haven't discovered an easy to to import external scripts into the Mongo CLI.  Ideally, this would work similar to Node.js require.

How can I get require working in Mongo CLI by default?

Or, is there some other way to solve external library dependencies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options for loading JavaScript into the `mongo` shell:

1) Save the JavaScript to `.mongorc.js` in your home directory.

2) Save the JavaScript to the [global `mongorc.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-global-mongorc-file) file (MongoDB 2.6+) which is evaluated before the `.mongorc.js` file in your home directory.

3) Use `load('filename.js')` from within the shell (or within one of the `mongorc.js` files).

4) [Store your JavaScript on the server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) using the `system.js` collection and `db.loadServerScripts()`.

For common JavaScript functions, the first option is the most typical approach.